# VBA "Select Case" not working on the other worksheet

Tags: vba

So my problem is: I use a specific code on one worksheet (Sheet1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Range("B24")

    Case "Standard"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Case "Medium"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case "High"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case Else
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select

End Sub
```

Once the Sheet2 becomes visible (based on the above), I have this code added to Sheet2 specifically:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Range("B14")

    Case "Medium"
        Rows("6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case Else
        Rows("6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End Select

End Sub
```

The problem is that the cell (Sheet2) B14 consisting of =Sheet1!B24 does not interact with the code on Sheet2 and thus doesn't hide/unhide rows. I need to physically select =Sheet1!B24 and click Enter in it and then the rows are hidden/unhidden. Please advise why it is not happening automatically.

PS. Calculation Ops are set to Auto

Thanks

Comment: I am struggling to understand. So, you change something in sheet1, then some action is performed depending on value in the cell B24 and then what you expect to happen?

Comment: It's all in the code. Basically if the value in cell B14 on Sheet2 changes it should perform certain actions (as described above). Unfortunately it doesn't. Instead I need to manually activate cell B14 and click Enter to initiate the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas don't trigger a "change" event. Use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Range("B24")

    Case "Standard"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Case "Medium", "High"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case Else
        Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Important:** Note the disabling of events before the code - this is to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi Macro, I do change my Sheet2 code to Worksheet_Calculate and now I receive this error: "Compile Error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: remove the `ByVal Target As Range` part - calculate event doesn't pass any arguments

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Thanks. PS. Can you recommend any resources (books/sites) where I can improve my VBA skills?

Comment: I've updated my answer - also "Medium" and "High" result in the same code so you can combine them in the case statement. WRT resources: here, cpearson.com, ozgrid.com are all good sites - there are hundreds of forums though so just see what works for you. Oh and there's a VBA Chat room on here also https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge